# Vue3 - Warning Component emitted event but it is neither declared in the emits option nor as an prop

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to remove some warnings for my project, which is in vue3 using vuetify3.

Currenlty I've a component that is a side dialog

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <slot name="activator" :show="() => setShowDialog(true)" :close="() => setShowDialog(false)" />
        <VDialog
            v-model="componentData.showDialog"
            @click:outside="onClickOutside"
            :width="componentProperties.width"
            :min-width="componentProperties.minWidth"
            :max-width="componentProperties.maxWidth"
            :content-class="contentClass"
            persistent
            transition="slide-x-reverse-transition"
        >
            <VCard v-show="componentData.showDialog" v-fill-parent>
                <VCardTitle v-if="hasTitle" :class="componentProperties.titleClass">
                    <VRow justify="center" align="center">
                        <slot name="title">
                            <span v-if="componentProperties.title">{{ componentProperties.title }}</span>
                        </slot>
                        <VSpacer />
                        <VCol v-if="componentProperties.showTopCloseButton" cols="1">
                            <VBtn
                                @click.stop.prevent="() => setShowDialog(false)"
                                color="transparent"
                                elevation="0"
                                size="medium"
                            >
                                <IconifyMdiClose />
                            </VBtn>
                        </VCol>
                    </VRow>
                </VCardTitle>

                <slot name="body">
                    <VCardText>
                        <slot name="content-prepend" />
                        <slot>
                            <slot name="content" />
                        </slot>
                        <slot name="content-append" />
                    </VCardText>
                </slot>
                <VCardActions>
                    <slot name="actions" :show="() => setShowDialog(true)" :close="() => setShowDialog(false)" />
                </VCardActions>
            </VCard>
        </VDialog>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Events } from '@enums/events';
export interface IDialogConfirmComponentProperties {
    modelValue?: boolean;
    modelData?: any;
    title?: string;
    isActive?: boolean;
    showTopCloseButton?: boolean;
    titleClass?: string;
    fillHeight?: boolean;
    persistent?: boolean;
    minWidth?: string | number;
    maxWidth?: string | number;
    width?: string | number;
}

export interface IDialogConfirmComponentEvents {
    (e: 'onOutsideClicked'): void;
    (e: 'update:isActive', val?: boolean): void;
    (e: 'update:modelValue', visible?: boolean): void;
}

export interface IDialogConfirmComponentData {
    showDialog?: boolean;
}

const componentProperties = withDefaults(defineProps<IDialogConfirmComponentProperties>(), {
    persistent: false,
    fillHeight: true,
    modelValue: false,
    isActive: true,
    showTopCloseButton: false,
    titleClass: 'pt-5 text-wrap',
    width: 'auto',
    minWidth: 650,
    maxWidth: 650,
});
const componentData = reactive<IDialogConfirmComponentData>({
    showDialog: false,
});
const emits = defineEmits<IDialogConfirmComponentEvents>();
const slots = useSlots();
const hasTitle = computed(() => !!slots['title'] || !!componentProperties?.title);
const contentClass = computed(() => {
    return ['side-dialog', componentProperties.fillHeight ? 'fill-height' : ''].join(' ');
});

function onClickOutside(payload: MouseEvent) {
    emits('onOutsideClicked');
    if (componentProperties.persistent) return;
    setShowDialog(false);
}

watch(
    () => componentData.showDialog,
    showDialog => {
        componentData.showDialog = showDialog;
        emitsDialogVisibleChanges();
    },
);
watch(
    () => componentProperties.modelValue,
    showDialog => {
        componentData.showDialog = showDialog;
    },
);
function setShowDialog(value: boolean) {
    componentData.showDialog = value;
}
function emitsDialogVisibleChanges() {
    if (componentProperties.modelValue === undefined || componentProperties.modelValue === null) return;
    emits('update:isActive', componentData.showDialog);
    emits('update:modelValue', componentData.showDialog);
}
</script>
<style lang="css">
.side-dialog {
    inset-block-start: 0 !important;
    inset-inline-end: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```

Which then I called like:

```html
<template>
    <SideDialog title="Configurations" show-top-close-button v-model="isDialogVisible">
        <template #activator="{ show }">
            <VBtn :variant="componentProperties.variant" @click.stop.prevent="show">
                <VIcon>mdi-cog</VIcon>
            </VBtn>
        </template>
        <VRow justify="center" align="center">
            <span>teste</span>
        </VRow>
    </SideDialog>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { ButtonVariant } from '@/types/vuetify';
export interface IConfigurationComponentProperties {
    variant?: ButtonVariant;
}
const componentProperties = withDefaults(defineProps<IConfigurationComponentProperties>(), {
    variant: 'plain',
});
const isDialogVisible = ref(false);
</script>
```

But I'm currently it's always consoling a warning saying:

> component emitted event "update:modelValue" but it is neither declared in the emits option nor as an "onUpdate:modelValue" prop.

Am I missing something trivial here? I mean I'm listening to the modelValue update event.

Why is it complaining about it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with your code. Please consider to remove all not necessary code to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using some code sandbox.

Comment: Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/keen-sanderson-u54mw6?selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A25%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A59%2C%22startColumn%22%3A25%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A59%7D%5D&file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FSideDialog.vue)

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74478614/2487565) to [vue 3 emit warning " Extraneous non-emits event listeners"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220737/vue-3-emit-warning-extraneous-non-emits-event-listeners) could help you.

Wrapping the template in a `<div>` fixes the warning.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot
...
    </VDialog>
  </div>
</template>
```

Please check if your emits still works as intended.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dry-glade-h492gb?selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A63%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A2%2C%22startColumn%22%3A63%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A2%7D%5D&file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FSideDialog.vue)